# jQuery - Check if a string is larger than 4 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, error-handling

I just have a quick question, im wondering if someone could help me.

I have the following script that someone has written which returns an error if there are no characters in the text field.

I want to modify the script so that it returns an error if there are less than 4 characters, but im not quite sure how.

Current script is as follows:

```
    if(!isString($.trim(iUsername.val()))){ //If username is not correct
        iUsername.siblings('.error').text('You must enter a username.');
        error = true;
    }
```

Comment: your title and your post body are contradicting; "larger" vs "less"

Comment: @BigJobbies see http://jsfiddle.net/VvD4s/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`if ($(textId).val().length < 4) { err; }`

right? :)

Comment: This isnt working if(!isString($.trim(iUsername.val().length < 4))){

Comment: tekknolagi's answer did not have `isString` nor `trim`.  Try the answer as given (but put the parens after `val` of course).

Comment: You need a `()` after `val`.  After fixing it, it will be a +1.